# "Index Out of Bounds" error when using the Split method for an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to split the data in this array, but it keeps giving me this error:

> index out of bounds.

The size of the array is 10. The line of code that is creating the error is

```
int score = int.Parse(scoreInfo[1]);
```

This is the code that I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int SIZE = 10;

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        // prompt the user
        Console.WriteLine("Enter player name and score on one line");
        Console.WriteLine("seperated by a space.");
        // Read one line of data from the file and save it in inputStr
        string inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        // The split method creates an array of two strings
        string[] scoreInfo = inputStr.Split();
        // Parse each element of the array into the correct data type.
        string name = (scoreInfo[0]);
        int  score = int.Parse(scoreInfo[1]);
        if (inputStr == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scoreInfo[j]);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Answer to your question depends on what input is entered. Please add input too.

Comment: What are you splitting your input on? Whitespace? Dash? Comma? Set a breakpoint on `inputStr.Split();` and see what it returns, Obviously it's returning an array with only one object in it.

Comment: The obvious answer is that `scoreInfo` actually has length 1, not 10.

Comment: Your split isn't actually going to do anything because you didn't specify a character to split on.

Comment: You also should move your if statement to directly after `string inputStr = Console.ReadLine();` as it does no good if you're already trying to parse without validating first.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot, it turns out that `Split` without any arguments splits on all whitespace characters.

Comment: You have to pass character in split() to split string use this link to better understand split method [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split). you can also mark breakpoint before `"int.Parse(scoreInfo[1]);"` to check if `scoreInfo ` has data

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code using a constant, something like "Guy 19". The .Split() method will break up your input string based on spaces. If you're not entering a space followed by a number, then your scoreInfo[1] will be empty and parsing will fail.

Try adding a break point after your .Split() to determine if scoreInfo is correctly split into a size 2 array, with [0] being the name of the player and [1] being an integer score. If you're entering a name like "FirstName LastName 20" then the information at position [1] is not going to be an integer and the parsing will also fail.

Your for-loop is sort of puzzling, are you looping through 10 times for a team of 10 players? You could put your dialog in a while loop and break out when parsing fails or the user types something like "exit".

Answer (score 0):

A few things of note. You are using `SIZE` to denote how many iterations your loop should make. It is not the size of your array. Your array is only going to be large as the split makes it. If you split with a space as the delimiter, you're going to have 2 objects in the array at indices 0 and 1.

That last section where you're saying to write `scoreInfo[j]` will fail as soon as `j` is larger than 1.

Comment: Agreed.  Based on assumption of the expected behavior given by the OP, `scoreInfo` should be initialized with a size of 10 before the `for` loop, increment the `for` loop to be `J+=2` then have have `string[] playerScore = inputStr.Split()` and set `scoreInfo[J] = playerScore[0]; scoreInfo[J+1] = playerScore[1]`.  That way at the end of the for loop `scoreInfo` will be an array with 10 elements (5 player's names and 5 scores)